# ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql, load

I'm trying:

```
mysql> 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/tmp/countries.csv' 
INTO TABLE countries 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES 
TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(CountryId,CountryCode,CountryDescription,CountryRegion,LastUpdatedDate,created_by,created_on)
SET created_by = 'DH_INITIAL_LOAD', created_on = current_timestamp();
```

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.`

It was working fine, I downloaded pymysql and mysql connector for the python script. I uninstalled and checked still it is not working.
The verion and infile is ON,

```
 select version() -| 8.0.17



mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please check also the rights of the folder you can also try to update it to an newer version

Comment: Remove `LOCAL` keyword - it is errorneous in your case. Then check: 1) Access rights (in the filesystem) for OS account which is used for MySQL daemon starting 2) `local_infile` system variable (done - ON is correct value) 3) `secure_file_priv` system variable 4) FILE privilege for MySQL account which is used for the query executing.

Comment: if I remove the local keyword , it throws me a error saying ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; - /tmp/
tried placing the file under /tmp and checked still facing the issue.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Known issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91872

for workaround when trying to connect to mysql in itself set local-infile to 1 and perform the load command:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 -h$MASTER_DB_HOST -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD  -D$MASTER_DB_NAME
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 76):

Using MySql Workbench 8 or above introduced this issue.  This fixed it for me:

> This restriction can be removed from MySQL Workbench 8.0 in the
> following way. Edit the connection, on the Connection tab, go to the
> 'Advanced' sub-tab, and in the 'Others:' box add the line
> 'OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1'.
>
> This should allow a client using the Workbench to run LOAD DATA INFILE
> as usual.

Quoted from this link:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91872

Answer (score 15):

For ubuntu:

1. edit the file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and add the following:

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

2. Restart the service

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

3. run: mysql -u root -p and check the local infile variable

   ```
     mysql> show global variables like 'local_infile';

     +---------------+-------+ 
     | Variable_name | Value |
     +---------------+-------+
     | local_infile  | OFF   |
     +---------------+-------+
     1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
4. ```
     mysql> set global local_infile=true;

     +---------------+-------+ 
     | Variable_name | Value |
     +---------------+-------+
     | local_infile  | ON    |
     +---------------+-------+
     1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
5. ```
     mysql> exit
     Bye
   ```

6. run

   ```
    mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p
   ```
7. ```
     LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/filename' INTO TABLE tablename;
   ```

Comment: Work perfectly in my case!

Answer (score 7):

To Fix this error (mysql 8):

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due
> to restrictions on access.

add the following line into your server's config file, under the "client" section:

```
[client]
loose-local-infile=1
```

That will fix the error.  However, this assumes you have already set the following under the "mysqld" section:

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=1
```

Having both parameters set in your config file will allow loading data from any directory.

Here's a simple example of use.  Run in the mysql terminal:

```
load data local infile '/path/to/file/data.tsv' into table my_table_name
 fields terminated by '\t'
 LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'
(
 `col1`,
 `col2`,
 `col3`,
 `col4`
);
```

Comment: This works for me, with mysql 8.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### For mac m1 users (Big Sur, Monterey, Ventura) :-

• First System Preferences --> MySql
"Stop MySql Server"

For macOS "Ventura" will go at the bottom of System Settings for MySQL

• Create etc/my.cnf file in /usr/local i.e ( /usr/local/etc/my.cnf )

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13XbMKYcmkzM4MGNCW0s70pfLqMDNhuoh/view?usp=sharing

• Now edit the "my.cnf" file using TextEdit:-

```
[client]
loose-local-infile=  1

[mysqld]
local_infile = 1
secure-file-priv = ""
```

follow the images as shown

[Step 1]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yZdk.png

[Step 2]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk9b1.jpg

Under connection --> Advanced --> Others (Edit it):-

```
 OPT_LOCAL_INFILE = 1
```

[Step 3]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlEJ5.jpg

• Under System Preferences "Start MySql Server"

• Always use it in your code in MySql Workbench for things to work

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
    
SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;   /* We can use here ON also in place of true */
    
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'/Users/ram/Downloads/DataSet.csv'
into table dress
FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
ENCLOSED by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

If you like this method then please upvote this post

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, if the above solutions don't work (and I am using mac OS Big Sur)

Go to the terminal and type

```
$ vi ~/.my.cnf
```

Then add this to the file

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = ''
```

Save and exit the window. Now go to terminal and restart mysql server using

```
$mysql.server restart
```

enter mysql server using

```
$ mysql -u <your username> -p
```

Now enter the following in mysql

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

This should show the value of the variable as blank.
Now if you use the query

```
load data local infile '<complete_file_path>' 
into table <table_name>
fields terminated by ',';
```

This should work! also make sure you have set the following variable to "ON" using:

```
set global local_infile = 1;
```

**Update**

For windows user - having mysql 8.0 installed following is the secure file variable mentioned above

```
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
```

Answer (score 0):

on windows :
for me after enabling local in both client and server and settings (in my.ini)

```
        [client]
          local_infile=1
        [mysqld]
          secure_file_priv=""

 the sql command ...
   load data local infile "FILE" 
 change to 
    load data infile "FILE"

works every time ...
so much so I do not even use the load local anymore and am not sure of the point of the command ...
```

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 2068: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access

On Windows 11 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor, build 22621.963, Version 22H2 - MySQL installed using the web installer .MSI file as a developer configuration.

Change my.ini from the default in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

In the [client] section add local_infile=ON

```
In the [mysql] section add local_infile=ON

In the [mysqld] section add local_infile=ON

Also change the line secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads" to secure-file-priv=""
```

The following code then works for me from MySQL Workbench connected to my local instance -

```
CREATE DATABASE northwind;

use northwind;
show tables;
create table shippers (
    shipperID int,
    company varchar(255),
    phone varchar(255)
);
```

Use this data by creating a .CSV file

```
ShipperID,CompanyName,Phone
1,Speedy Express,(503) 555-9831
2,United Package,(503) 555-3199
3,Federal Shipping,(503) 555-9931
```

Copy the .CSV file to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\northwind

This code works to load the shippers table -

```
use northwind;
#SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
#SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local_infile";
LOAD DATA INFILE 'nw_shippers.csv' 
INTO TABLE shippers 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
select * from shippers;
```

Also for MySQL

SELECT VERSION(); gives '8.0.31'

Help > About Workbench gives "Version 8.0.31 build 2235049 CE 64 bits"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for laravel than visit this [link](https://tenerant.com/blog/using-load-data-local-infile-in-a-laravel-migration/)
In case link is not working, you need to add the `MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` to your PDO options. You can do this in config/database.php in the mysql block of the connections array: `'options'  => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps for **Windows 10**, **MySQL 8.0** and using **CMD**:

1. Log into MySQL with local-infile=1:

> **mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p**

2. Make sure local_infile variable is ON:

> **mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';**
>
> ```
> +---------------+-------+
> | Variable_name | Value |
> +---------------+-------+
> | local_infile  | ON    |
> +---------------+-------+
> ```

3. If this is OFF set to true:

> **mysqld> SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;**

3. Add or check that the following lines are under the **[client]** and **[mysqld]** section of your my.ini configuration file: (Mine was located under 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0')

> [client]
> **loose-local-infile=1**
>
> [mysqld]
> **local_infile=1**

4. Use LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE

**AND** make sure the path to your data is seperated by '**/**'

> LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE '*C:/Path/To/Your/File.txt*' INTO TABLE
> *yourtable*;